# Passing variables to a view in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The scenario is this. First pick one or more players from the list and click shuffle button. Use javascript ajax to post the variable(s) to a controller method called **Shuffle** to make a list from those variables. Finally call **Shuffled** method to pass that list into a view. The problem is that the list being printed is **null**.

**Edit to be more clear:** Ajax is just passing the selected values to the controller method called `Shuffle`

**JS Ajax**

```
$("#shuffleBtn").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Players/Shuffle",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: arr }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);  
        }
    });
});
```

**Shuffle**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Shuffle(int[] id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
            Player player = db.Player.Find(id[i]);
            playerList.Add(player);
        }
        return Shuffled(playerList);
    }
```

**Shuffled**

```
    public ActionResult Shuffled(List<Player> list)
    {
        ViewData["PlayerList"] = list;
        return View(list);
    }
```

**The View**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Shuffled";
}

<h1>
    list: @ViewData["PlayerList"]
</h1>
```

Comment: Don't just call `Shuffled` as you are dropping the result. Return it: `return Shuffled(playerList);`

Comment: `@ViewData["PlayerList"]` is razor code - its evaluated when the view is fosrt rendered and you ajax call does not change it. Return the view in the `Shuffle()` method - `return View("Shuffled", playerList);` and update the DOM

Comment: @Andrei @Stephen When I return the view in `Shuffle()` method, I get `Http 404 error` for `Players/Shuffle`

Comment: Then your doing something else wrong as well. And what is the point of `window.location.href = "/Players/Shuffle";`? You making an ajax call which is for staying on the same page and there is no point making a redirect. And the `Shuffled.cshtml` view should have `@model List<Player>` if you wanting to display the items in the collection

Comment: Sorry, debugging is the point of `window.location.href`, I forgot it there. Fixed it now, still no redirection but I can see the html in console which is proper.

Comment: What do you mean _still no redirection _? Its an ajax call. Ajax NEVER redirect - the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page.

Comment: i think you should return json as your ajax call content type is json

Comment: @navnit, `contentType` specifies what you send to the view (`dataType` is for what you get back)

Comment: There is no problem with ajax, I know it doesn't redirect anything. It just pass the variables to the `Shuffle` method. The problem begins there. Url is ~/Players at the beginning. I picked some players and clicked shuffle button. Then there is no difference at the page which I referred as "no direction".